# Not Proper Table Alignment in Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to develop an application with help of Bootstrap in order to respect Desktop, Tablet and Mobile.

Currently I'm facing an issue with the table responsiveness

Below I have provided the screenshot and the code, kindly let me know where i do a mistake.

You can see from the second screenshot, where the second getting aligned to responsiveness but the other not.

**Screenshot 1 :: Perfect alignment on tablet**

[image]

**Screenshot 2 :: Not perfect on mobile**

[image]

**CODE ::**

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">
    <link rel="icon" href="../../favicon.ico">

    <title>Fixed Top Navbar Example for Bootstrap</title>

    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="js/libs/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

    <!-- Custom styles for this template -->
    <link href="js/libs/bootstrap/customcss/navbar-fixed-top.css" rel="stylesheet">

  </head>

  <body>

    <!-- Fixed navbar -->
    <div class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top" role="navigation">
      <div class="container">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Project Title</a>
        </div>
        <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>

            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Mission <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">

                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Request <span class="caret"></span></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">

                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li class="dropdown-header">Nav header</li>
                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">One more separated link</a></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
          </ul>
          <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
            <li><a href="../navbar/">Default</a></li>
            <li><a href="../navbar-static-top/">Static top</a></li>
            <!--li class="active"><a href="./">Fixed top</a></li -->
          </ul>
        </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
      </div>
    </div>

    <div class="container">

      <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Project Title</h1>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p>
          <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="../../components/#navbar" role="button">View navbar docs &raquo;</a>
        </p>
      </div>


       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="panel panel-warning">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">

                <div class="col-md-12">
                <table class="table table-bordered table-condensed files" border="1">
                  <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Emp Id</th>
                        <th>Emp Name</th>
                        <th>Start Date</th>
                        <th>End Date</th>
                        <th>Days</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                        <th>Status</th>
                    </tr>
                  </thead>
                  <tbody>
                     <tr>
                        <td>123456</td>
                        <td>Employee First & Last Name</td>
                        <td>04/DEC/14</td>
                        <td>30/JAN/15</td>
                        <td>35</td>
                        <td>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-success">
                                <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-ok-sign"></i>
                                 <span>Validated</span>
                            </button>
                        </td>
                        <td>
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">
                             <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></i>
                                 <span>Pending</span>
                            </button>     
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                  </tbody>
                </table>
              </div> 

            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>



    </div> <!-- /container -->


    <!-- Bootstrap core JavaScript
    ================================================== -->
    <!-- Placed at the end of the document so the pages load faster -->
    <script src="js/libs/jQuery/js/jquery-2.0.3.js"></script>
    <script src="js/libs/bootstrap/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is working fiddle'
http://jsfiddle.net/52VtD/9293/

```
<div class="container">

      <!-- Main component for a primary marketing message or call to action -->
      <div class="jumbotron">
        <h1>Project Title</h1>
        <p></p>
        <p></p>
        <p>
          <a class="btn btn-lg btn-primary" href="../../components/#navbar" role="button">View navbar docs &raquo;</a>
        </p>
      </div>


       <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-12">
          <div class="panel panel-warning">
            <div class="panel-heading">
              <h3 class="panel-title">Panel title</h3>
            </div>
            <div class="panel-body">

               <div class="table-responsive"> 
        <table class="table table-bordered">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Row</th>
                    <th>First Name</th>
                    <th>Last Name</th>
                    <th>Email</th>
                    <th>Biography</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>John</td>
                    <td>Carter</td>
                    <td>johncarter@mail.com</td>
                    <td>
                         <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">
                             <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></i>
                                 <span>Pending</span>
                            </button>     
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>Peter</td>
                    <td>Parker</td>
                    <td>peterparker@mail.com</td>
                    <td>
                         <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">
                             <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></i>
                                 <span>Pending</span>
                            </button>     
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>3</td>
                    <td>John</td>
                    <td>Rambo</td>
                    <td>johnrambo@mail.com</td>
                    <td>
                         <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning">
                             <i class="glyphicon glyphicon-question-sign"></i>
                                 <span>Pending</span>
                            </button>     
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>

            </div>
          </div>

        </div>
      </div>
```

Comment: but this is the only way, where we can make responsiveness in case of long table?

Comment: You can the problem is in button, i has fixed with try to make responsive buttons